# PHP auction script using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to create a auction site in PHP using AJAX to refresh the page once a user has entered a higher amount of money.

I can handle the PHP side of it okay but I was wondering if AJAX can really be used so that it refreshes often without putting a lot of strain on server resources?

I also plan to use JQuery to implement AJAX as this makes the job a whole lot easier. Anybody have any code examples that you think could be used?

Any help would be appreciated/

Thanks!

Comment: Re code examples, the manual has some: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentHighestBid=0;
setTimeOut(getHighestBid,5000); //5000ms wait before polling for a better price

function getHighestBid()
{

    $.ajax(
    url: url, // ur php end point,
    type: "GET"
    data: {}   //json data if you want to send anything as a querystring parameter to your servre
    dataType:"json"
    success: function(response)
    {

        if(response.currentMaxBid>currentHighestBid)
        {
        currentHighestBid=response.currentMaxBid;
        //code to update your markup
        }

    }

});
```

Hope that made sense..

Read abt [json in php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Comment: Yeah thanks that kinda makes sense. I do need to look into the best method of getting the new price. I'm guessing you will have to send the ID of the item via GET or POST to a PHP file which then returns the price...

Comment: why do you want to post doesnt make sense.. id should be sent in using the data parameter: data:{id:"2323"}. FYI rememeber to mark the answer if it helped..

Comment: One thing I don't understand is how the PHP can access the currentMaxBid variable? Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: you can send it as part of you r query string paramater.. data:{id:"2323",currentHighestBid:currentHighestBid} and in php access it as $_GET("currentHighestBid").. but i dnt ustand why you wnat to read it in php shouldnt you have all the bid values on your server stored in a db or smthing

Answer (score 1):

Polling would work as "zzzz" mentioned. Comet (Push based instead of Polling) would be a nicer/better solution for this use case. However PHP is not really good at this with high traffic sites. Node.JS with Socket.IO would be a good solution for you :)

Comment: haha!! there we go with node.js and sockets.. let me remind u all are part of HTMl5 spec and will nt work on legacy browsers..

Comment: I haven't really encountered Node.JS and Socket.IO before but i'm guessing it tries to fix the problems with AJAX to get the data in real time? I will need to look at some tutorials.

Comment: Yeah I assumed that they would be, but legacy browsers (especially ie6) will not need to be supported as this is just a project im doing myself.

Comment: Socket.IO has Flash fallback. So legacy browsers are supported.

Comment: Can I just clarify, Node.JS is for the client and Socket.IO is the websocket server? Or are they one and the same?

Comment: Node.JS/Socket.IO are server side. Part of Socket.IO is of course Client side to handle the incoming/outcoming data. Node.JS is a asynchronous server and Socket.IO is build on top of that. It's better to use an async server since a sync server like Apache can't "hang" connections easily.

Comment: Thanks, yeah after some reading I understand that its basically a dedicated server for asynchronous requests. It sounds like the way forward!